# UIView animation completion block not called when animation is interrupted

Tags: objective-c, uiview, core-animation, uiviewanimation, caanimation

I'm trying to call a method whenever this animation ends but in some occasions for example, when user leaves the app, its completion block never gets called.
Also when a VC appears with its animation at the same time as the UIView animation, the completion block never gets called.

What should I do to make sure the callback is called even if the animation is interrupted somehow?
Should I not use UIView animation completion block at all and use something else instead? Please enlighten me..!

```
-(void)action {

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{

                     self.doorLeft.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.doorLeft.frame.size.width, self.doorLeft.frame.size.height);
                     self.doorRight.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width -self.doorRight.frame.size.width, 0, self.doorRight.frame.size.width, self.doorRight.frame.size.height);

                 } completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     if (finished) {
                         switch (self.type) {
                             case 0:
                                 [self.delegate startTOship];
                                 break;
                             case 1:
                                 [self.delegate gameTOship];
                                 break;
                             case 2:
                                 [self.delegate shipTOgame];
                                 break;
                             case 3:
                                 [self.delegate shipTOmap];
                                 break;
                             case 4:
                                 [self.delegate gameTOmap];
                                 break;
                             case 5:
                                 [self.delegate mapTOgame];
                                 break;
                             case 6:
                                 [self.delegate mapTOship];
                                 break;
                         }

                         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                                               delay:0.5
                                             options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                                          animations:^{

                                              self.doorLeft.frame = CGRectMake(-self.doorLeft.frame.size.width, 0, self.doorLeft.frame.size.width, self.doorLeft.frame.size.height);
                                              self.doorRight.frame = CGRectMake(self.doorRight.frame.size.width *2, 0, self.doorRight.frame.size.width, self.doorRight.frame.size.height);

                                          } completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                              if (finished) {

                                                  [self actionEnded];
                                              }
                                          }
                          ];
                     }
                 }
 ];}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do, is use `CATransaction` instead.

```
[CATransaction begin];

[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
    [self actionEnded]
}];

[UIView animateWithDuration:8.3 delay:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{

    self.doorLeft.frame = CGRectMake(-self.doorLeft.frame.size.width, 0, self.doorLeft.frame.size.width, self.doorLeft.frame.size.height);
    self.doorRight.frame = CGRectMake(self.doorRight.frame.size.width *2, 0, self.doorRight.frame.size.width, self.doorRight.frame.size.height);

} completion:nil];

[CATransaction commit];
```

If the animation is interrupted at all, the completion block is called almost immediately The block is also called when animation completes uninterrupted.

P.S: `CATransaction` works with all `UIView` animations. As long as you say `begin` before the animation happens and `commit` after the animation code.

Comment: Hmmm what if I have a "chained" animation that has several animations one after another like so in my edited question?

Comment: Then add the commit block after the last animation code.

Comment: Hmm but I think I'd have to go with CAKeyframeAnimation after all because what I'm doing needs exactly that. Does CAKeyframeAnimation also make sure its completion block gets called immediately when animation is interrupted or do I have to use it along with CATransition..?

Comment: I haven't used CAKeyframeAnimation. But I suspect it might behave the same way.

Comment: I've just learned that this answer is completely wrong. CATransaction does not work with simple UIView animation blocks. You must use subclass of CAAnimation all the way for the entire thing.

Comment: Well it works perfectly for me. Block is called reliably each time animation is complete.

Comment: Well, I had a same situation but this code didn't work for me.